# Why is a WinUI application suddenly giving "Access Denied" on one PC?

Tags: c#, .net, winui

I have an unpackaged WinUI 3 (1.1.4) app running on several computers.

The app isn't doing anything exciting, just displaying some presentation text for large monitors. It isn't accessing anything from the file system or anything that would require elevated permissions (all other computers using the app run it as a normal user).

On one particular computer today, the application has stopped working. The only thing showing indicating failure is the Windows event log (Application) which is showing:

- Event Id: 5
- Source: Windows App Runtime
- Message: Access is Denied

Has anyone encountered this? Can't find anything online relating to it including Microsoft's own support groups and GitHub issues page (will post there later if no one knows what this is, they tend to take a while to respond).

I've tried:

1. Giving the app elevated admin permissions
2. Deleting the application folder and replacing the program files (it works on my development PC and every other computer with it deployed)
3. Giving the containing folder the 'Everyone' user full permissions
4. Rebuilding the app with a different assembly name (in case there are folders creating in a temp directory somewhere by the WinUI framework)
5. Checked for additional logs but found none (the application isn't making it to the start-up function as the first thing it does is generates a log file)
6. Putting in a line at program startup to write a text file, this doesn't occur so it looks like the program isn't reaching anything in the startup function

No idea what else to try, the error is incredibly vague. Hoping someone else has had this experience recently and can help.

Comment: What I could find, searching google, is that Event ID 5 is due to a corrupt user registry database. Try with another user on the same machine

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/registry-hive-corrupted-event-id-5-kernel-general/275d080b-4d29-4eed-887d-bee55725c602

Comment: Will give it a try later on, however I was under the impression that the error codes were application specific (e.g. 5 in this instance is not related to 5 generated by the WinUI runtime). I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Does it happen to any WinUI app running on the machine? Even   for empty basic app?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I created another admin user, no luck same issue.

Comment: @BorisR Tried a blank app, it fails with the same error - Win32 0x05 - Access Denied. This would indicate it's a machine level problem, problem is what. May try uninstalling and re-installing the runtime. It is difficult to establish what the problem is without any meaningful debug/error logging info.

Comment: Seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2918) in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Yep seems like that exact issue/workaround, glad someone took the time to log and it get Microsoft to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it's fixed. It's something to do with 1.1.4, downgraded to the previous version of the WinUI/Windows App SDK and it works fine.

Same thing occurred with the blank app (asked by BorisR), once downgraded it worked fine otherwise the same issue, 'access denied'. Still not sure why this problem is only occurring on this particular computer, I'll be forwarding on what I can to Microsoft for investigation.